# iPhone:COREPLOT:Remove Empty space between two labels

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

In iPhone App I am using coreplot for displaying Vertical Bar Graph

How to remove empty spaces between two consicutive Axis Labels?

ie on x-Axis       Label1.........Label2........

on Y Axis

Label1

.

.

Label2

Please Help and Suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The labels are centered on the corresponding major tick marks. You'll have to adjust the distance between the tick marks. How you do that depends on which labeling policy you're using.

Comment: In my case labeling policy is CPAxisLabelingPolicyName so how ti0 fix this problem.

Comment: Make your tick locations closer together.